# error while using QDomDocument

Tags: qt

when i use  QDomDocument it shows QDomDocument is not atype....then i add #include...then also it show the error as no such name space.....y it  happend....

Comment: post a short code snippet and the **exact** error messages you're getting.

Comment: i got the answer friends i add in .pro file as QT +=xml;

Comment: If you use CMake: add `qt5_use_modules(${PROJECTNAME} Xml)` after `add_executable`

Answer (score 17, accepted):

QDomDocument belongs to the [QtXml module](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtxml-module.html).

To link against the module, add this line to your `qmake` `.pro` file:

```
QT += xml
```

Comment: Furthermore, if you are using Qt Creator, try 'Run qmake' under Build menu, this seems always to be a ultimate solution